# layout xml does not run

Tags: android-layout, android-studio

I'm not sure why when I run my emulator, everything in my Layout XML doesn't appear but the emulator only shows everything that is in my Menu Xml.
Hope someone can help. Thank you

(Using Android Studio)

The layout xml is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout                           xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.example.zainuddeen.myapplication.Main2Activity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
    android:theme="@style/AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        app:popupTheme="@style/PopupOverlay">

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

and menu xml is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:title="@string/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search_black_48dp"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>

<item
    android:id="@+id/action_favorite"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_favorite_black_24dp"
    android:title="@string/action_favorite"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>

<!-- Settings, should always be in the overflow -->
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    app:showAsAction="never"/>

<item android:id="@+id/action_share"
    android:title="@string/action_share"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider"/>
```

Comment: does that shows in preview ? provide xml code.

Comment: Try to rebuild your project or restart android studio.

Comment: If you are unable to preview your layout design, then there must be an exception or error log, can I have that?

Comment: The code on my layout.xml is as follows:

Answer (score 0):

I think you design different xml and run different

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

put the name of layout in R.layout.mylayout